# how to check the first item in ion-select

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to make the first item in the list to be always checked but checked="true" does not seem to be working

```
 <ion-item>
        <ion-label class="label">Change City</ion-label>
    <ion-select checked="true" [(ngModel)]="cityName"(ionChange)="getCity()">
      <ion-option class="option" *ngFor="let city of City" value='{{city.cname}}' >{{city.cname}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
       </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should remove **checked="true"** from ion-select and try to checked from the .ts file like this:-

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {

    this.cityName= '**your city name**';


  }
}
```

> Note:- **checked="true"** not working because you used this in
>   ion-select so, inside the ion-select all option are occur.So it can't
>   get which option you want to check from ion-select.

Comment: If its work perfectly then you should upvote and accept this answer by which other person also use this when they have the same problem.

Comment: I did but I get  this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." and it return to 0